# Object reference not set to an instance of an object XML document object c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Xml-документ, необходимо воссоздать объект по его структуре

- У каждого элемента Chapter есть Position .
- Position имеет один элемент Resources.
- В Resources есть Tzr и Mat, но не в каждом
  Position

Классы создаю такие

```
class Position
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public List<Tzr> tzrCollection { get; set; } 
}    

class Chapter
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Position> positions { get; set; }     
}

class Tzr
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

**Вопрос** - как добраться до tzr или mat, если имеются Position без mat или tzr? Если обращаться криво (мои способом) - то возвращает ошибку

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
        var chapters = from c in doc.Element("Document").Element("Chapters").Elements("Chapter")
                       select new Chapter
                       {
                           Caption = c.Attribute("Caption").Value,

                           positions = (from p in c.Elements("Position")
                                        select new Position
                                        {
                                            Caption = p.Attribute("Caption").Value,
                                            Quantity = p.Attribute("Quantity").Value,

                            tzrCollection = (from t in p.Element("Resources").Elements("Mat")
                                                where t != null
                                                select new Tzr
                               {
                                    Caption = t.Attribute("Caption").Value

                               }).ToList()
                                         }).ToList()
                       };
```

Comment: Пример `xml` покажите

Answer (score 0):

> Xml-документ, необходимо воссоздать объект по его структуре

Это называется десериализация.

В твоем случае нужно до конца описать структуру xml-файла, т. е. добавить еще один класс Document:

```
    public class Document
    {
        public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
    }
```

Дальше десериализуем:

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));
        XmlTextReader xr = new XmlTextReader(@"path\to\Data.xml");
        Document doc = (Document)serializer.Deserialize(xr); // получаем объект из xml
        List<Chapter> chapters = doc.Chapters; // получаем список объектов Chapter
```